# Create oracle workspace with sqlplus in installshield?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, installshield, sqlplus

I am in the process of creating an installer that automates the oracle installation process using InstallShield; however, I am running into problems.

Basically, what I need to know is if there is a way to create the Oracle workspace from the InstallShield source so that it is automated for the user.

I'm pretty new to InstallShield and setting up Oracle, so in case I am calling it the wrong name, I am referring to the following:

Once Oracle is installed, Click on the "Get Started" shortcut in the "Oracle Database 11g Express Edition" folder.  Then, Click on the "Application Express" button.  This is typically used to create a workspace by the user, and I need to automate the process using InstallShield and sqlplus (unless there is another way to do it from within InstallShield).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, let me say that I have successfully managed this but I hope that no one else has to do this.  One of the problems I've had to deal with is the apparent lack of support for 64 bit operating systems that Oracle Express 11g has... anyway...

What I did was create a batch file that calls two .sql scripts.  I ran that batch file with the LauchAppAndWait(..) function in InstallShield.

The .sql files that are called in the batch files accomplish two separate tasks.  The first script creates the new workspace that is necessary with similar syntax to the following:

```
connect system/password as sysdba
alter session set CURRENT_SCHEMA = APEX_040000;
begin
APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.ADD_WORKSPACE(null,'[SCHEMA]','[SCHEMA]',null);
END;
/
```

Just a note on that, the "APEX_040000" will be reliant on what version of Oracle is installed (I think?).

The second script accomplishes adding the new user (I'm not familiar with Oracle-but I believe this is the same as a user?).  This is accomplished with code similar to the following:

```
connect system/password as sysdba
CREATE USER [name of the user] PROFILE DEFAULT IDENTIFIED BY [password]
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP
ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
GRANT CONNECT TO [username];
GRANT RESOURCE TO [username];
ALTER USER [username] QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;
/
```

Now, I want to warn anyone who uses this that I am new to doing this, so I am not 100% sure that all of this is necessary.  All I know is that it works for my purposes.  I would like to encourage anyone who reads this to correct anything that isn't quite right or comment and explain why/if something I did is against standards.

The batch file calls the two scripts with syntax similar to the following:

```
set "path=%1"
set "var1=[name of the script that sets up the workspace]"
set "var2=[name of the script that adds the user]"

echo exit | "[The complete path to sqlplus.exe]" /nolog @%path%%var1%
echo exit | "[The complete path to sqlplus.exe]" /nolog @%path%%var2%
```

Note on the batch file : Adding the "echo exit | " before the command to execute the script was the only way I could get sqlplus to exit after each script.  Without doing that it would just hang after the script executed.  I believe the actual functionality is that the "echo exit " is appended to the end of the parameter on the right as input (but again, I could be wrong).

I apologize if any of this is incorrect/bad practice/irritates you.  Again, this was just the workaround that I found to fit my needs and I am open to discussion on how this is done properly; however, I didn't get any responses so... here's this! lol.

I hope this helps someone somewhere because it was a pain to figure all of this out for myself.